# aiohttp redirect without return

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a route function that executes an async function that takes a long time to return. Therefore when you go to that route, the page will not redirect for a long time:

```
@routes.get('/test')
async def test(request):
    asyncio.ensure_future(startService()) # code that blocks test from returning immediately
    return web.HTTPFound('/test') # Will not redirect for a few seconds.
```

To fix this I thought there must be a way to redirect without the redirect being the return statement. However I have not found a way to do this.

I have also tried `try, finally` block, however it didn't help.

Thanks :)

Comment: `ensure_future` shouldn't block anything. Is the "code that blocks" sync or async?

Comment: @user4815162342 it is an async infinite loop (repeats code every 5s)

Comment: Are you sure that the code it runs doesn't contain something blocking, like a call into `requests` or other blocking lib?

Comment: @Manu `repeats code every 5s` - using `await asyncio.sleep(5)`, correct?

Comment: It uses await asyncio.sleep(5) correct. However it does use a blocking lib and that is likely what is causing the wait. Do you think there is no fix for that?